# Saving Settings in Reducer & Accessing them from another Reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux

I have a settings reducer:

```js
state = {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 400,
    ...etc.
  },
```

I have a different reducer, which needs access to the fontSize of the settings-reducer. I don't know now how to access this state now. What would be an easy & viable solution?

Comment: why would you need access at reducer A from reducer B? what is the business?

Comment: You have an option of moving it to a separate file and importing into both the reducers.

Comment: How could I do this @PrathapReddy? So far, everything I found had the logic neatly separated. Could I somehow import the state of the settings-reducer into my current reducer?

Comment: are these settings changed somehow with an action? do you want to listen to updates on these settings?

Comment: yes, exactly. The user can change the font-Size and that's reflected in the app then. I have one reducer for all the settings & one reducer for the article. Now the problem is not to change the fontSize on screen on change of the fontSize in the settings reducer, the problem is that my other reducer needs the fontSize to calculate something. (I know that this is probably not the best practice, but went for this architecture anyways for other reasons)

Comment: why don't you add code to handle the same action to the other reducer too to handle there the changes?

Comment: because I need the fontSize in the other reducer. If I tried handling everything in the settings reducer, I would run into the same problem, namely, that I would need data from the other reducer i don't have available in the settings reducer. :(

Comment: How are you dispatching the `fontSize` update action in you code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding through comments,

You can achieve what you need as below

- Keep the initial state `fontSize` value in both the reducers.
- Whenever user updates `fontSize` of **settings reducer** by an `action`, have an another action dispatched with the same value of `fontSize` to update your **article reducer** and to calculate new value out of it (You can store it with a different name in article reducer depends on your requirement)
- Now you will be having updated `fontSize` in **settings reducer** as per user update, new calculated value based on the updated `fontSize` in **article reducer** along with the original (initial) `fontSize`.

```js
// Assuming you are using thunk middleware

// While dispatching action for fontSize update
updateFontSize (fontSize) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: UPDATE_FONT_SIZE, fontSize});
    dispatch({type: GET_UPDATED_FONT_SIZE, fontSize});
  }
}


// settingsReducer.js
const initialState = {
  fontSize: 30,
  fontWeight: 400,
  ...
}

reducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case UPDATE_FONT_SIZE:
      return {...state, fontSize: action.fontSize};
  ...
}


// articleReducer.js
const initialState = {
  fontSize: 30,
  ...
}

reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_UPDATED_FONT_SIZE: // Different action, with different data update based on fontSize
      return {...state, additionalValue: (action.fontSize / 2)};
  ...
}
```